# Scrollbars not functioning correctly when centering element

Tags: html, css, centering

When centering the `#outer` div, the scrollbar starts not on the top left of the element but on the center. It becomes impossible to read the beginning of the text, and a part of the border is cut off.

How could I center and be able to scoll and see all content, including the border, when the content `#outer` is larger than the parent `#container`, using css?

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

#outer {
  width: max-content;
  border: 1rem solid black;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#inner {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">The beginning of this text is missing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar ex ut volutpat iaculis. Mauris a tellus vel mauris ullamcorper semper quis non quam. Nullam in scelerisque dolor, vel cursus odio. Nulla dignissim imperdiet mauris eleifend ultricies. Sed auctor tortor nec neque mollis feugiat. Aliquam tincidunt lacus at dictum elementum. Aliquam nunc lacus, lobortis vitae finibus et, vehicula eget nibh. Suspendisse eget tincidunt quam. In posuere quam ac neque sagittis, at finibus ante dignissim. Proin magna enim, bibendum quis pulvinar eget, porttitor non dui. Sed mollis placerat sem, id condimentum libero tempor quis. Maecenas ultrices tellus vel nisi mattis, sit amet scelerisque urna gravida. Nullam eu ipsum vitae eros pulvinar fringilla id ut massa. Fusce vitae rhoncus nulla.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of `display:grid;`
, because when I removed that, the content is showing itself fully.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  place-content: center;
}

#outer {
  width: max-content;
  border: 1rem solid black;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#inner {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">The beginning of this text is missing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar ex ut volutpat iaculis. Mauris a tellus vel mauris ullamcorper semper quis non quam. Nullam in scelerisque dolor, vel cursus odio. Nulla dignissim imperdiet mauris eleifend ultricies. Sed auctor tortor nec neque mollis feugiat. Aliquam tincidunt lacus at dictum elementum. Aliquam nunc lacus, lobortis vitae finibus et, vehicula eget nibh. Suspendisse eget tincidunt quam. In posuere quam ac neque sagittis, at finibus ante dignissim. Proin magna enim, bibendum quis pulvinar eget, porttitor non dui. Sed mollis placerat sem, id condimentum libero tempor quis. Maecenas ultrices tellus vel nisi mattis, sit amet scelerisque urna gravida. Nullam eu ipsum vitae eros pulvinar fringilla id ut massa. Fusce vitae rhoncus nulla.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know much about grid, but I think another fix might be the width;

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

#outer {
  width:100%;
  border: 1rem solid black;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#inner {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">The beginning of this text is missing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar ex ut volutpat iaculis. Mauris a tellus vel mauris ullamcorper semper quis non quam. Nullam in scelerisque dolor, vel cursus odio. Nulla dignissim imperdiet mauris eleifend ultricies. Sed auctor tortor nec neque mollis feugiat. Aliquam tincidunt lacus at dictum elementum. Aliquam nunc lacus, lobortis vitae finibus et, vehicula eget nibh. Suspendisse eget tincidunt quam. In posuere quam ac neque sagittis, at finibus ante dignissim. Proin magna enim, bibendum quis pulvinar eget, porttitor non dui. Sed mollis placerat sem, id condimentum libero tempor quis. Maecenas ultrices tellus vel nisi mattis, sit amet scelerisque urna gravida. Nullam eu ipsum vitae eros pulvinar fringilla id ut massa. Fusce vitae rhoncus nulla.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know if you want it on separate lines.

Comment: Unfortunatly without `display: grid;` or `display: flex;`, the content is not centered. For the second one, it still has the original problem but this time vertically. I do not want to set a height because I want that to be dynamic. Thank's for the effort though.

Comment: Center it you can try margin:auto;

Comment: I would also like to have it vertically centered, wich is not possible with `margin: auto;`